# How to remove array of object in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

```
    <?php
$test = '{
    "100": {
        "name": "Sports",
        "contentID": "100"
    },
    "200": {
        "name": "Village",
        "contentID": "200"
    }
}';
$idWiseData = json_decode($test,true);


$test2 = '[
    {
        "contentID": "100",
        "contentStatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "contentID": "200",
        "contentStatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "contentID": "300",
        "contentStatus": "active"
    }
]';
$allTopics = json_decode($test2,true);

foreach ($allTopics as $key => &$topic) {
        $contentInfo = [
            'contentStatus'     => $topic['contentStatus']
        ];
$topic['contentName']  = isset($idWiseData[$topic['contentID']]['name']) ? $idWiseData[$topic['contentID']]['name'] : null;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($allTopics);
?>
```

Above code is working fine, i am not getting my expected output. actually `$allTopics` having 3 objects (contentID 100 & 200 & 300).`$idWiseData` having object (contentID 100 & 200).
I want to take `name` value from **$idWiseData** and replace to **$allTopics** based on contentID.
contentID 300 don't have name so should not come this object.

> Expected out put

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 100
            [contentStatus] => active
            [contentName] => Sports
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 200
            [contentStatus] => active
            [contentName] => Village
        )

)
```

> I am getting output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 100
            [contentStatus] => active
            [contentName] => Sports
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 200
            [contentStatus] => active
            [contentName] => Village
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 300
            [contentStatus] => active
            [contentName] => 
        )

)
```

Kindly anyone update my code please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you, you need to `unset()` the index within the array if `contentName` is `null`. This can be achieved by using [unset()](https://www.php.net/unset)

```
foreach ($allTopics as $key => &$topic) {
    // your code here ....

    if (is_null($topic['contentName'])) {
        unset(allTopics[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a record from the array by using [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). But I would recommend you to change your code and have a 3rd array which must be your result, so then you don't need to change any of your source data.

Answer (score 0):

You're not deleting the index from the array just setting contentName to null. Use [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to delete the index from the array.

Try this one:

```
<?php
$test = '{
    "100": {
        "name": "Sports",
        "contentID": "100"
    },
    "200": {
        "name": "Village",
        "contentID": "200"
    }
}';
$idWiseData = json_decode($test,true);


$test2 = '[
    {
        "contentID": "100",
        "contentStatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "contentID": "200",
        "contentStatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "contentID": "300",
        "contentStatus": "active"
    }
]';
$allTopics = json_decode($test2,true);

foreach ($allTopics as $key => &$topic) {
        $contentInfo = [
            'contentStatus'     => $topic['contentStatus']
        ];
        if(isset($idWiseData[$topic['contentID']]['name'])){
            $topic['contentName'] = $idWiseData[$topic['contentID']]['name'];
        } else {
            unset($allTopics[$key]);
        }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($allTopics);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach ($allTopics as $key => &$topic) {
        $contentInfo = [
            'contentStatus'     => $topic['contentStatus']
        ];
$topic['contentName']  = isset($idWiseData[$topic['contentID']]['name']) ? $idWiseData[$topic['contentID']]['name'] : null;
if (is_null($topic['contentName'])) {
      unset($topic['contentName']);
  }
}
```

USE THIS CODE THIS MIGHT SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM.